# How to accept user license and Aggrement while installing an application using cmd

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to install an application in Windows 7 using cmd. while installing, it pops out for user license and agreement and I have to accept that for further installation. I used /S with the .exe file but still, it is popping the license window. I am trying to install "wget" for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

I am trying something like this for installation using cmd:

`wget.exe`

What should be the syntax of cmd installation so that it should not ask for acceptance of license or how to pass yes with the command so that it can be installed without popup?

Answer (score 1):

You can first try  **wget.exe /?** or **wget.exe /help** in a cmd to get the help windows which usually displays all accepted parameters of the setup.
Also you can check the application vendor web-site. Usually in Support section you can find install instructions which include accepted parameters.

Additional there is a chance setup exe files accept also msi parameters : AGREETOLICENSE" or "ACCEPTEULA" are the ones of interest to you .

In that case , to pass MSI parameters you should use the /v"[your parameters and property]" switch.

Example : Setup.exe /v"/l*v c:\test.log" /v"MYPROPERTY1=value1" /v"/qb"

In your case you can try :

**wget.exe /v"AGREETOLICENSE=yes ACCEPTEULA=Yes /qb"**

Notice the /s silent parameter has been replaced with /qb inside the syntax.

If non of the above works, then it means the setup exe has been developed in a bad practice way of silent install and parameters support.
It happens a lot of time unfortunately.